# What is an agent in the Quantum Bayesianism/Relational Quantum mechanics-like interpretations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

In interpretations like [Quantum Basyesianism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Bayesianism), Relational interpretation, Information Theory interpretation, etc, the wavefunction represents the probabilistic knowledge that an **agent** holds about a Quantum System. This knowledge is not an incomplete information about some underlying hidden variables. Instead, it's said that the probabilistic knowledge is fundamental.

The wavefunction here describes relative probabilities like in the Bayesian school of probabilities. This solves the [Wigner's friend](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend) paradox by saying that the wavefunction collapses relative to Wignner's friend, but is uncollapsed relative to Wigner until Wigner makes a measurement.

My problem is:

What is an agent, precisely? To do physics, we have to make the "agent" mathematically rigorous. Since this "agent" is part of the definition of the theory, we have to define it as something fundamental. If we said that an agent is some macroscopic object holding something like a memory chip, then it'd be a circular definition because we'd be defining a fundamental theory like Quantum Mechanics in terms of a macroscopic object. All macroscopic phenomena should be derived from Quantum Mechanics, not the other way around.

How much progress has been made in making this "agent" mathematically rigorous?

Comment: If you read the explanations by QBism's creators (QBism being a particular brand of Quantum Bayesianism), they would likely strongly disagree with your statement that "to do physics, we have to make the "agent" mathematically rigorous".  An agent is a person, and that's the end of the story. A "macroscopic object holding something like a memory chip" can't assign a probability distribution. Neither can a mouse or perhaps even a chimpanzee. It's at least a category error, I think, (under this interpretation of QM) to say that agents need be to be part of the theory.

Comment: Whether you agree with him or not, (founder of QBism) Chris Fuch's writings are enjoyable, and eminently readable.  It might be worth scanning the ArXiV for both his expository and more mathematical works.  Same for Blake Stacey.  If you want some of the early foundational stuff (what is closer to Quantum Bayesianism as most people might understand it, because QBism takes a radical subjective approach), look for Chris Fuch's earlier work with Rudiger Schack and Carlton Caves. In any case, getting things from the horses' mouths might be your best bet here!

Comment: @march There must be some related interpretations which don't treat humans as fundamental? I will change the title to that. What about the relational interpretation and information theory information? I just want to ask about a Bayesian-ish interpretation (any interrpetation which treats wavefunction as relative) which attempts to make the agent rigorous.

Comment: I've read mostly QBism stuff, so that's what I jumped to.  I will point out that what I said isn't entirely correct, because QBism has no problem (as far as I understand it) treating other agents as quantum systems themselves.  See QBism's explanation of Wigner's Friend, as you've mentioned in your OP. As for the relational interpretation (Rovelli, I think?), I was never really able to understand what it was getting at, but I didn't try that hard. As far as information-theoretic interpretations, that's likely broad enough for there to be multiple answers to the question.

Comment: In any case, I can't really help you here, since I'm at best a quantum foundations dabbler (and not even a dilletante), but I will say that it's possible that *no* such interpretations aim at making the agent "mathematically rigorous", since that seems antithetical to the whole approach.

Comment: @march In popular talks, I've heard people talk about agents mathematically in terms of "entropy" and stuff. But that seemed circular to me because entropy is a statistical mechanics idea. Statistical Mechanics is emergent from Quantum Mechanics. QM should not be defined in terms of SM. "because QBism has no problem (as far as I understand it) treating other agents as quantum systems" Indeed. This the most attractive feature of these interpretations to me. Everything in the universe evolves unitarily until measurement by the agent.

Comment: I've always interpreted the "agent" as just a way to remark that the theory describes *your* state of knowledge about the physics. Why do you need to model what the "agent" is? QM tells you that you need to describe things from the point of view of what you know about them, and thus in a probabilistic fashion. If you went on and try to model the agent itself it would defeat the whole purpose. It would be again building a theory assuming that it's possible to describe things as "existing objectively" rather than just describing your subjective knowledge about them

Comment: @glS This is extremely problematic though. What is it about humans that makes them agents? Why aren't inanimate objects agents? If QM is a fundamental theory, it should be able to explain this property of humans because humans are made of atoms. Otherwise, there is a more fundamental theory than QM.

Comment: @RyderRude I don't think it's about humans at all. It's about the purpose of a physical theory being to describe observations from a subjective point of view. But it's not like a "smart enough" "inanimate object" wouldn't be able to use QM, so it's not about humans. Imo the "asymmetry" is about a part of the system trying to describe the rest of the system given their current knowledge/prior about it.

Comment: @glS But where, among biological beings, do you draw the line? Is a cow an agent? Is bacteria agnet? Anything that is "smart enough" to use QM gets counted as an agent? But physics should be able to model this "smartness" as smartness is a physical phenomenon. Physics should be able to analyse a system, and tell whether it has agent properties or not.